# 4:2:2 to 4:4:4 YCbCr converter in verilog

Tags: image-processing, video, verilog, video-processing, system-verilog

How can I convert a 4:2:2 YCbCr datastream into 4:4:4 YCbCr in Verilog?
I am new in verilog and I don't know from where should I start. I tried creating 2D array but I have no idea how to implement it in this question.

```
module test3(clk,datastream_in,datastream_out);
input clk;
input [11:0] datastream_in [0:7];   //input datastream 

output [17:0] datastream_out[0:7];      //output datastream

reg [17:0] datastream_out[0:7];

reg  temp2[0:7];            //temporary variables to store the value from the input
reg  temp3[0:7];
reg  temp4[0:7];

integer i;
integer y;

always@(posedge clk)
begin

assign i=0;
assign y=0;

while(1)
begin

datastream_out[y]=datastream_in[i+0];    
temp2=datastream_in[i+1];
datastream_out[y+1]=temp2;
temp3=datastream_in[i+2];                          //input pattern 0123 :      4:2:2
temp4=datastream_in[i+3];                          //output pattern 013213 :4:4:4 
datastream_out[y+2]=temp4;
datastream_out[y+3]=temp3;
datastream_out[y+4]=temp2;
datastream_out[y+5]=temp4;
i=i+5;
y=y+6;
end 
end
endmodule
```

ERROR:251 CANNOT ACCESS MEMORY temp4 DIRECTLY.
ERROR:252 CANNOT ASSIGN AN UNPACKED TYPE TO A PACKED TYPE

Comment: You need to separate the algorithm from the implementation, at least as a first pass. If you could show how you would normally convert 4:2:2 YCbCr datastream into 4:4:4, then we could look at the Verilog.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm is to repetitively store the input from the datastream i.e 4 bytes and assigning the output accordingly for 6bytes where the pattern repeats.

Answer (score 0):

If your storing bytes you want to use:

```
module converter (
  input      [7:0] datastream_in [0:11], //input datastream 
  output reg [7:0] datastream_out[0:5]   //output datastream
);


reg [7:0] temp2;            //temporary variables to store the value from the input
reg [7:0] temp3;
reg [7:0] temp4;
```

Assign is generally used for wires, **not** assignment to registers inside always or initial processes. The byte selection and assigmnets should be along the lines of:

```
i=0;
datastream_out[i]   =datastream_in[i+0];    
temp2               =a[i+1];
datastream_out[i+1] =temp2;
temp3               =datastream_in[i+2]; //input pattern 0123 : 4:2:2
temp4               =datastream_in[i+3]; //output pattern 013213 :4:4:4 
datastream_out[i+2] =temp4;
datastream_out[i+3] =temp3;
datastream_out[i+4] =temp2;
datastream_out[i+5] =temp4;
```

Temp2 has this assignment: `temp2=a[i+1];` `a` Has not been mention any where else in the code snippet is this a typo?

I am not sure what your trying to with the following:

```
while(i!=10) begin
  i=0;
```

`i` never gets incremented.